# Grails Send Version as part of a PUT request

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Using Grails 2.3.9

I'm trying to send the version number as part of a PUT request. In the controller side I do actually receive it (request.JSON) but when populating that data with `instance.properties = params` it is missing.

Is there a flag I have to set in Config.groovy to have the "version" populated too, similar to `grails.converters.domain.include.version = true` for having the "version" in the request?

If not, is this achievable in another way?

Update: this should be independent of the sent data (JSON or XML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you do not want the version field to be populated during data binding but if that really is what you want, you can configure it to be bindable...

```
class SomeDomainClass {

    // ... 

    static constraints = {
        version bindable: true
    }
}
```

Make sure that is really the behavior you want before doing that though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending the request as `JSON`, then you need to set the properties with it. Use:

```
instance.properties = request.JSON
```

instead of

```
instance.properties = params
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion: in both cases it happens the same thing: the "version" field is not populated (I can see a different value in request.JSON), while the rest is.